# How to draw a rounded rect widget using paintEvent?

Tags: c++, qt

In this picture, left is a QLabel drawn using only `styleSheet`, and on the right is my attempt at drawing the same label but `without` styleSheet, mainly in its `paintEvent`:

[image]

It's almost the same, the problem is, its rounded borders are getting cropped/deformed, take a look at the borders extremity on the top, left, right, and bottom, what I'm missing?

```
class PaintLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    int borderRadius = 12;

    PaintLabel(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QLabel(parent)
    { 
        QFont font = parent->font();
        font.setPixelSize(18);
        font.setWeight(QFont::Weight(900));
        setFont(font);
    };

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override
    {
        //QWidget::paintEvent(event);
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
 
        // BACKGROUND
        painter.setBrush(QColor(Qt::red));
        painter.drawRoundedRect(rect(), borderRadius, borderRadius);
    
        // BORDER
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor("#810004"), 2));
        painter.drawRoundedRect(rect(), borderRadius, borderRadius);

        // TEXT
        painter.setPen(Qt::white);
        painter.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, text());
    }
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindowClass())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QLabel* styleSheetLabel = new QLabel(this);
    styleSheetLabel->setGeometry(200, 200, 24, 24);
    styleSheetLabel->setStyleSheet(R"(
        background-color: red; 
        border: 2px solid #810004;
        border-radius: 12px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 900;
    )");
    styleSheetLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    styleSheetLabel->setFixedSize(QSize(24, 24));
    styleSheetLabel->setText("!");
    styleSheetLabel->show();

    QLabel* paintLabel = new PaintLabel(this);
    paintLabel->setGeometry(240, 200, 24, 24);
    paintLabel->setFixedSize(QSize(24, 24));
    paintLabel->setText("!");
    paintLabel->show();
}
```

Comment: [From the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#drawRoundedRect): "A stroked rectangle has a size of `rect.size()` plus the pen width." If you want to fit into a given rectangle, you need to shrink what you pass to `drawRoundedRect` by the pen width.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i tried `rect.adjust(-1, -1, -1, -1)` after `setRenderHint` and `rect.adjust(1, 1, 1, 1)` before drawing the border, but it is still different, I'm confused about how to adjust the rect.

Comment: try `QRect r = rect(); r.adjust(1,1,-1,-1);`, and then use `r` in your `drawRoundedRect`

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene it still look different, the borders looks jagged

Comment: Are the borders cropped like in your screenshot? And why don't you use `drawEllipse` instead of `drawRoundedRect`?

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene how would it be using drawEllipse? as the ellipse expects a QPoint

Comment: there are many overloads of `drawEllipse()`, see this one: [QPainter::drawEllipse(const QRect &rectangle)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#drawEllipse-1), and event if this did not exist, you could give it `rect().center()` or something like that.

Comment: I figured out the problem, i need to set the pen transparent before drawing the background, or it will mess with the border.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
int borderRadius = 11;
```

or...

```
QLabel* paintLabel = new PaintLabel(this);
paintLabel->setGeometry(240, 200, 25, 25);
paintLabel->setFixedSize(QSize(25, 25));
paintLabel->setText("!");
paintLabel->show();
```

The geometry is too tight for your radius + border width; this gives one pixel of extra room for your 2 pixel border width.